# withFallback keyword when using akka

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe-config

What does the pattern keyword withFallback stands for and how is it used.

Can someone help with this syntax and maybe provide some examples.

How be the call to withFallback used?

```
object Worker extends App {
  val config =
    (if (args.nonEmpty) ConfigFactory.parseString(s"akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=${args(0)}")
    else ConfigFactory.empty).withFallback(
      ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.cluster.roles = [worker]")).
      withFallback(ConfigFactory.load())

  val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)
  val worker = system.actorOf(Props(new Worker), name = "worker")

}
```

Can you provide other examples of using it?

Comment: This is not related to akka, but to typesafe config.

Answer (score 6):

Akka uses the typesafe-config lib, which in turn uses the HOCON format, for configuration files. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md).

`withFallBack` allows to merge two different configs, the first one having priority over the second one.

For instance:

**conf1**

```
foo.bar = baz
foo.baz = bar
```

**conf2**

```
bar.baz = foo
foo.baz = foo
```

Then for `conf = conf1.withFallback(conf2)`:

```
conf.getString("foo.bar") == "baz" 
conf.getString("foo.baz") == "bar" 
conf.getString("bar.baz") == "foo"
```